# Send http request from flutter emulator to localhost api / win10

Tags: flutter, api, http, localhost

I have API on my PC and flutter emulator.
When I test my API  via fiddler post Json - `http://localhost:51797/test` it works fine.

When I try to call my API via flutter     `var url = Uri.parse('http://localhost:51797/test');`
I get this message

> I/flutter (29903): http://localhost:51797/test E/flutter (29903):
> [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception:
> SocketException: OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111, address =
> localhost, port = 52824

Then I read that I must use `var url = Uri.parse('http://10.0.2.2:51797/test');`
and when I do it I get

> http://10.0.2.2:51797/test E/flutter (29903):
> [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception:
> FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1) E/flutter
> (29903): <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML
> 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html...

What else can be done here to solve this problem ?

Comment: Seems like it is an error with the response returned, could you please add the code related to the http request and what is the output you obtain when making a request on this endpoint with a software such as Postman.

Comment: I send simple json, problem is that backend did not receives it.
I have logging on the back end side, and from fiddler and postman it logs requests.
But when I send request via flutter nothing is logged on the back end.
Postman > http://localhost:51797/test - works fine.